# Is TcpClient.Available threadsafe?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Can `TcpClient.Available` be called at the same time `Write` to its `NetworkStream` is called, is it threadsafe?

Comment: What happened when you tried to do that?

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: Are you trying to read data by one thread and write with another simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance methods on TcpClient are not guaranteed to be thread safe as stated on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Only the public static members of the class are guaranteed thread safe

Comment: The question here is about not only `TcpClient` class but also its field `NetworkStream` which may seem to be unrelated.

Comment: @myWallJSON because TcpClient is not thread safe for instance members you may have issues with writing the NetworkStream on a separate thread while reading TcpClient.Available